# WebLogic Classpath does not append the classpath options under server start

Tags: weblogic, weblogic9.x

When I add some new directories, jars etc to the WebLogic classpath under Server Start, it somehow does not append these values to the existing classpath. It just replaces the existing classpath with what I have provided in ClassPath under Server Start.

To get around this problem, I need to put the existing classpath under Server start and then add the additional classpath directories.

Is there a way to tell WebLogic to consider the values specified under ClassPath to be treated as additions to the already existing classpath?

Comment: Your question is IMO unclear. Can you try to clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: do you mean Server Start via console?

Comment: @Kaushik were you able to solve this problem?